# CKEditor not working (grayed buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm testing a configuration for CKEditor, but I can't type and the buttons are like this:

[image: Grayed buttons]

This is on Chrome 42.0.2311.152 m (64-bit), but the same happens on Firefox and IE.

Here's how I'm loading CKEditor:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ckeditor.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="teste"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('teste');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a link to my CKEditor build: [link](http://ckeditor.com/builder/fac82a662d6b1f396bb62aa56f809452)

Also, here's what I get when trying to click on one of the two dropdown menus or one of the two clickable buttons:

[image: Error]

And here's line ckeditor.js:618:

```
showBlock:function(a,b,c,i,f,h){var j=this._.panel,l=j.showBlock(a);this.allowBlur(!1);a=this._.editor.editable();this._.returnFocus=a.hasFocus?a:new CKEDITOR.dom.element(CKEDITOR.document.$.activeElement);this._.hideTimeout=0;var d=this.element,a=this._.iframe,a=CKEDITOR.env.ie?a:new CKEDITOR.dom.window(a.$.contentWindow),g=d.getDocument(),o=this._.parentElement.getPositionedAncestor(),p=b.getDocumentPosition(g),g=o?o.getDocumentPosition(g):{x:0,y:0},m="rtl"==this._.dir,e=p.x+(i||0)-g.x,k=p.y+(f||
```

Sorry if I missed something, I'm not a very good programmer. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This package is broken! You can see that by going directly to `ckeditor/samples/jquery.html` - the same result.

I've just downloaded new package of CKEditor version 4.4.7 Standard (from http://ckeditor.com/download) and it's working perfectly OK. Try to do the same ;)

Comment: Yeah, going to ckeditor/samples/jquery.html gives me the same result. But you mean that my configuration, with the plugins I chose, is broken? I need those plugins, how can I make it work?

Comment: Could you name them? Did you remove any plugins from standard version?

Comment: Yes, but I thought I have removed only the unnecessary things. On the following link you can see my build (and download it):
http://ckeditor.com/builder/fac82a662d6b1f396bb62aa56f809452

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to only add new plugins without removing ones. I thinkt that's the answer for your issue. If that doesn't work then one of the plugin breaks it, but it's for sure build configuration problem not implementation...

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll try downloading the full version with my extra plugins and then remove the unnecessary ones manually on the config file. If it works I'll update here. Thanks.

Comment: It worked! I got the minimal version and added my plugins, without removing any of the base plugins.

Comment: BTW. I can see that it was the `wysiwygarea` plugin missing. It's a base for the classic editor which will not start without it.

Comment: @Reinmar that was EXACTLY the problem, no need to do anything else, thank you!

Comment: had same issue, spent couple of hours figuring it out. weird thing was that inline editor was working without problems.